# CSS get broken after multiple refresh

Tags: php, html, css, refresh

I noticed that my design get broken randomly after multiple refresh. It's working fine on my localserver.

[image]
[image]

Only the header's display seems to fail. The header is included on the webpage using a php include. The rest of the page, that is not the header, is always displayed properly.

I noticed that, if I force the image on the header to reload after every refresh, I have more change to get a not broken design after a refresh, my best guess is it has something to do with some ressources not getting loaded at the right time. I haven't noticed anything wrong using Firebug.

The website address is : http://apprendreavec.fr/prof/

Any guess ?

Thanks !

Comment: No problem here, seems fine. Chrome 33. Maybe it trys to load it from the cache file. Try `shift + F5` or `CTRL + F5`.

Comment: You're onto something, when I hit "CTRL+F5" multiple time, it doesn't get broken. So the best solution would be to force the header not to be stored in the cache ?

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue more then anything. Like I said it works fine on all my browsers. FF, IE and Chrome.

Comment: So this is a browser issue, even if it's working fine on my side if I do not cache the header ? There must be some way to prevent this, if I can reproduce the issue, I'm pretty sure many users will too.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime you refresh page multiple time, that time it is possible that browser not load document completely, so CSS not load properly.

It is also possible that if network speed is low then document need time to load completely.

Comment: So why it is working everytime when I do not cache the header ?

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem, it look like broken because it still loading,. some css js or html is not fully loaded that is why it look like broken

Comment: What do you mean by "It's still loading" ? If I hit the refresh button, and the browser stop loading, my CSS is broken, and it's not going to try to load it again, until I hit the refresh button again.

Comment: i think that is bug, the browser did not load some of your file. do you have any js for delay and timing?

Comment: I don't have any JS for delay and timing, should I add some to make sure the css is loaded properly ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your css, as the other says browsers dont load after few refreshes.

The only problem that i see here user can feel that your css is loading when your page opens.

Try to avoid it using javascript delay or timing methods. For example;

[1 - Example Delay Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_delay.asp)

[2 - Example Timing Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)